# OpenCV Human Body Detection through a webcam - No detections visible

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection

I am trying to detect the human body through OpenCV. The code throws no error.  The camera also starts but it is unable to detect anything.

```py
import cv2

classifier = cv2.CascadeClassifier(r'C:\Users\dhruv\Desktop\DataScience\haarcascade_fullbody.xml')
 

video_captured = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
 
while (True):
   
    ret, frame = video_captured.read()
    frame = cv2.resize(frame,(640,360))
    gray_frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
 
    # pass the frame to the classifier
    persons_detected = classifier.detectMultiScale(gray_frame)
 
    # check if people were detected on the frame

for (x, y, w, h) in persons_detected:
    cv2.rectangle(frame, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), (255, 0, 0), 2)    
    cv2.imshow('Video footage', frame)
    
    if (cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q')):
        break

#cv2.VideoCapture(0).release()
```

Answer (score 0):

I highly suspect its an indentation error.  The camera does start, but your code to draw the bounding boxes of the faces are outside of the loop.  Just indent that code.  In addition, you'll need to free the camera resource properly or the next time you run the code, the camera will not be able to capture frames properly.  I've changed the release call so that it releases the grabbed resource.

```py
import cv2

classifier = cv2.CascadeClassifier(r'C:\Users\dhruv\Desktop\DataScience\haarcascade_fullbody.xml')
 

video_captured = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
 
while True:
   
    ret, frame = video_captured.read()
    frame = cv2.resize(frame,(640,360))
    gray_frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
 
    # pass the frame to the classifier
    persons_detected = classifier.detectMultiScale(gray_frame)
 
    # check if people were detected on the frame

    for (x, y, w, h) in persons_detected:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), (255, 0, 0), 2)    
        cv2.imshow('Video footage', frame)
    
    if (cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q')):
        break

video_captured.release()  # Changed so that you're releasing the grabbed resource
```